# WSO2-emm: How can i create a BKS file that is compatible with Android?

Tags: ssl, wso2, wso2-iot

I am configuring `wso2-emm`, the step which I stuck in is [android configuation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/Android+Configurations), as it said in tutorial :

> If the SSL certificate is self signed, use the [CA certificate PEM file
>   that is generated for iOS](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/iOS+Server+Configurations#iOSServerConfigurations-step2) to create a BKS file that is compatible with
>   Android

I follow the instruction about iOS, but it create .jks file not .bks file which is required for android. 
I try to convert .jks file to .bks using Portecle but I get the following error:

```
java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException : Cannot recover key.
```

How can i create a BKS file that is compatible with Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow these steps: step 2 to step 8 https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/iOS+Server+Configurations#iOSServerConfigurations-step2

After that, you can generate the BKS file using following command:

keytool -noprompt -import -v -trustcacerts -alias 'openssl x509 -inform PEM -subject_hash -noout -in ca_cert.pem' -file ca_cert.pem -keystore emm_truststore.bks -storetype BKS -providerclass org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath bcprov-jdk16-146.jar -storepass 'wso2carbon'

Note: you need to have bcprov-jdk16-146.jar in the folder in order to generate above bks file

Once you generate it copy emm_truststore.bks to Android res/raw folder. In android source code CommonUtilities.java change SERVER_PORT to 9443 and SERVER_PROTOCOL to https://

Comment: thanks @Chatura, I follow the instruction, but when I run the final command I get this error : `Illegal option: x509`

Comment: You probably have done something wrong when generating keys. I have tested it and it worked. please repeat the steps and make sure you are not getting any errors.

Comment: I repeat the steps, but I get same error. here is the [link](ceit.aut.ac.ir/~9031020/CA certificate PEM file.docx) of steps that I have done with the ir resault. what is the differnce between keystore password and keystore key password in level 8th in tutorial (7th in mine)

Comment: I run this command instead `keytool -noprompt -import -v -trustcacerts -alias "openssl x509 -inform PEM -subject_hash -noout -in ca_cert.pem" -file ca_cert.pem -keystore emm_truststore.bks -storetype BKS -providerclass org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath bcprov-jdk16-146.jar -storepass 'wso2carbon'` but when I try to export the project as an Android application I get  `Invalid keystore format` !

Comment: Please refer to the docs, I have mentioned in the answer and please make sure Certificate Authority (CA) and Registration Authority (RA) certificates should be created as version 3 certificates as mentioned in the docs

Comment: I follow the doc steps and your instruction afterward, as you can see each step screen shot in this [link](http://1drv.ms/1aBbm73), but I really got stuck in this stage and I would appricate your help.

Comment: You don't want to use those keys you have generated to export the Android project. You can use a new key pair as mention in Android docs to export the project. http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that the password for reading the private key is wrong. Have you used the same password for the keystore and the key-entry?

Another problem may be that the BouncyCastle library has changed the BKS file format some years ago - therefore you need the old Bouncycastle version.

Android uses the old BKSv1 which can be created by [KeyStore Explorer](https://keystore-explorer.org/).

Comment: I used Portecle v1.7 and same password for the keystore and the key-entry!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to directly convert jks file to bks format using Portecle. But you can use the key file & pem file generated for obtaining CA certificate for iOS. For that you'll need to create a new keystore of BKS format using Portecle & then import the pem file for the keypair & then the key file afterwards.